# What is the denial of the sentence "$u(x)\in\bigcup_{k\in\mathbb{Z}} A_k$ for all $x\in [0, C]$"?

Tags: real-analysis, calculus, solution-verification

Let $C>0$ and consider
$$\bigcup_{k\in\mathbb{Z}} A_k,$$
for some suitable subsets of $\mathbb{R}$. I am trying to understand what is the denial of the sentence "$u(x)\in\bigcup_{k\in\mathbb{Z}} A_k$ for all $x\in [0, C]$".

I think it would be: "at least $x_0\in [0, C]$ exists such that $u(x)\in\mathbb{R}\setminus\bigcup_{k\in\mathbb{Z}} A_k$."

Could someone please tell me if is so?

Thank you in advance!

Comment: Yes, that is correct.

Comment: @KaviRamaMurthy thank you for your comment.

Comment: @User1010 Do you mean: Are $\lnot\forall_x A$ and $\exists_x\lnot A$ equivalent for some formula $A$?

Comment: This is the type of stuff that one would discuss in a logic lecture.

Answer (score 2):

The sentence "at least $x_0\in [0, C]$ exists such that $u(x)\in\mathbb{R}\setminus\bigcup_{k\in\mathbb{Z}} A_k$." is a bit strange. First of all, it should be twice $x_0$, or twice $x$, and I would rephrase it as follows

> there exists $x \in [0, C]$ such that
> $u(x)\in\mathbb{R}\setminus\bigcup_{k\in\mathbb{Z}} A_k$.

or, denoting by $S^c$ the complement of $S$,

> there exists $x \in [0, C]$ such that
> $u(x)\in\bigcap_{k\in\mathbb{Z}} A_k^c$.